# Mongoose query.select() Not functioning properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When defining a query with Mongoose, you can use:

```
query.select({somefieldname: 0}) // selects everything but 'somefieldname'
query.select({somefieldname: 1}) // selects only 'somefieldname' & '_id'
```

However, when I combine them:

```
query.select({somefieldname1: 0, somefieldname2: 1})
```

I receive an error.  I'm fairly new to Mongoose so perhaps I am overlooking something, any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: attempts to filter the data before sending the response are also not working. For some reason.. "delete responseJSONObj[sensitiveKeyName]" is doing nothing at all.

Comment: Found a solution to my problem using .lean() during my query.  Then I was able to simply delete the keys from the resulting items prior to sending the response.  Not exactly what I wanted and I still think it would be great if Mongoose supported MongoDB native functionality.

Answer (score 3):

> You cannot combine inclusion and exclusion semantics in a single projection with the exception of the _id field.

[mongodb projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#result-projections)

Comment: That's too bad, really.  It's a native functionality of MongoDB.  I guess I should rtfm.